# HTML input control replaced by adding a new control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ng-if, formarray

I am working on Angular reactive forms, I want to add controls dynamically to Angular form array. But when I add a select box or text area previously added controls are also replaced by the newly added control. I think there is some issue in my HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="reviewForm" >        
        <span *ngIf="isClicked">              
          <div formArrayName="controlArray">
            <div 
              class="form-group"
              *ngFor="let control of reviewForm.get('controlArray').controls; let i = index">            
              <label>{{label}} </label>   
              <!-- {{selectedControl.attributes.value}}              -->
              <span *ngIf="!(selectbox || textarea);else dropdown">
                <input 
                  type="{{control.value}}"                                      
                  class="form-control"     
                  placeholder="abc"                                                  
                  [formControlName]="i"
                  >
              </span>
              <ng-template #dropdown>
                <span *ngIf="selectbox;else comment">
                  <select
                    class="form-control"
                    [formControlName]="i">
                    </select>                                     
                </span>  
                <ng-template #comment>
                  <span *ngIf="textarea">
                    <textarea name="Comment" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>  
                  </span> 
                </ng-template>  
              </ng-template>                                             
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </span>
        <button type="button" (click)="addControl()">Add</button>  
        <!-- <button type="button" (click)="clicked()">Add</button><br />                 -->
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button> -->
      </form>
```

Here is the component class code:

```
addControl(){    
      this.isClicked = true;
      const control = new FormControl(this.selectedControl.name, Validators.required);
      (<FormArray>this.reviewForm.get('controlArray')).push(control);      
      switch(this.selectedControl.name){
        case 'select':
          this.selectbox = true;
          break;
        case 'textarea':
          this.textarea = true;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      // console.log(this.selectedControl);            
    }
```

**its the stackblitz demo url of my project:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjiu8x

Please help.

Comment: Well you are using variable `label`, which means that all have the same label. What do you actually want to store to your form ?, now you are just storing string of the type you choose from the select to your formarray, not objects, which I'd assume you want?

Comment: I am trying to add controls dynamically to form to make it generic. its not intended to store some specific data.

Comment: Then why are you using reactive form if you do not need it? :)

Comment: I don't know why previously added controls are replaced when I add select box and text area.

Comment: I have been asked to use reactive forms in this project.

Comment: But if you do not need it, then have just an array, or alternatively set the reactive form on the actual FORM, and not the iteration of selected data ;)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point

Comment: You are now applying a formarray, whereas I would assume that the selections like the dropdown etc should be the actual form, not the data that has been added.

Comment: ...alternatively have all your fields as a form, now you only have a formarray which makes no sense.

Comment: User may add any number of controls as required. If I use formcontrol instead of formarray then how can I assure any number of controls.

Comment: What I mean, include all your template as form, makes no sense to have an actual form where you make all the choices, which currently is not a form (makes no sense?) you only have your formarray, when I see that your actual form is where you make the choices. Sure, you can have the form array as well. But anyway, the problem you are facing is that you are using variable `label`, that is why all your labels are the same in the template.

Comment: I don't have problem with same labels, the problem is why previously added controls are replaced with the selectbox and text area?

Comment: have you run my project with the provided link of stackblitz?

Comment: plz run my project and add a text field, then add a select box. then you will identify the problem that I'm facing. text box will also be replaced with the select box.

Comment: Yes, and the problem is that you are not implementing the formArray correctly, as I said early, your current formArray just contains strings, which then of course messes with the output. I also said, that I don't understand why you are using a formarray there, I would swap it around, have the choices you make as a form, and the listing as an array. But that is how I see it :)

Comment: Just check this, see how your form array looks like the last part of template. There are just strings when you add items. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuc4my?file=app/app.component.html Also commented how I see what should be the form :)

Comment: Anyway, if you want to go with the current setup, I suggest you read this: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/ You need to push formgroups to your formarray, not just a single formcontrol.

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82 , I got your point. Working on it.